# Prepare for ARC - best strategy?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

For an OS X app for Lion, 64-bit only, I was wondering what the best strategy is in order to be prepared to take the app to ARC later on:

- Do normal retain/release and simply remove it all later
- Use automatic garbage collection and hope the changes needed later will be minimal

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: If you're already requiring Lion and 64-bit, why not do ARC from the start?

Comment: Current build of 4.2 is more stable, if that helps :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do GC. It's not recommended for new apps anymore, and it's a bigger conceptual jump to ARC than manual reference counting is.

I'd just use ARC in the first place, but if you really want to write the program in something else and then convert it, use MRC. Xcode offers an automatic converter for this.

Comment: Agreed, definitely don't do GC. There is no automatic migration tool for GC projects (which is lame, and I've filed a bug) which means that moving from GC to ARC is harder than it should be. There are also difficult problems if you make use of the weak collections like NSMapTable/NSHashTable as these don't use weak references with ARC. I have a large GC project that is proving very problematic to move across. Non-GC projects are a doddle by comparison.

Answer (score 5):

The only preparation necessary is to:

1. Write modular code (hopefully, you're doing this already).
2. Ensure you're following [Cocoa memory management and naming conventions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html).

ARC can be activated on a per compilation unit basis, and will happily interact with non-ARC code that has these properties. You can thus adopt it gradually.

There's a good video on ARC adoption in the [WWDC 2011 videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/), titled "Introducing Automatic Reference Counting". I can't link right to it (it's behind an access control wall, and you'll need an Apple developer account).

Comment: The suggestion to write modular code is a good one. Any problem becomes easy if broken into enough small pieces.